# Is there a simple way to know the starting value of a select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'd like to do this simply without saving the starting value of the select in an object.

if i have (when i load the dom):

```
<select>
  <option value='1' selected>one</option>
  <option value='2' >Two</option>
```

and than i later change the selection so that another option is selected, is there some kind of property that stores the value of the option that was originally selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the defaultSelected property of the options object to test if it was selected by default.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/select.shtml

Comment: Nice way of starting off your SO career! Let's see if all your answers become accepted answers! :-)

Answer (score 5):

I think this sholud work:

```
$("select option[selected]").val()
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4dCMd/

Tested this way in different browsers: seems to be broken in IE7/8, works in last Chrome, FF and IE9

Comment: it works thanks, i was thinking about a javascript properties or some obscure DOM trick but this is really ok!

Comment: But yes, of cours is broken in explorer, so i'll need something different!

Comment: the answer by Gigabyte is exactly what i was lloking for, as it is cross browser. Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$('select').find('option[selected]').val();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zu5af/)**

Answer (score 0):

simple to use filter to get any default selected options:

```
var def = $("select > option").filter(function () { 
    return this.defaultSelected; 
});
```

[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/9G3pR/)

#### [DefaultSelected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLOptionElement)

Reflects the value of the selected HTML attribute. which indicates whether the option is selected by default.

Comment: He wanted the original selected value, not the current selected value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').each(function(){
  $(this).data('originalValue',$(this).val());
});
```

You could do this on .ready. It'll store the default values of every select in it's data object.

---

Oh just re-read your question and you said that's exactly what you don't want.
Well, i don't think there's another efficient way to do it so i'll leave it here anyway.